# Case types integer and time without time zone cannot be matched

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, time

I have my code as below:

```
Songs.objects.filter(clients__id__in=client)\
    .annotate(
        logic_value=Case(
            When(after_n_values__isnull=False, then="aftervals_songs"),
            When(specific_time__isnull=False, then=F('specific_time')),
            distinct=True,
            output_field=models.TextField()))\
    .values('logic_value')
```

Here, I am getting an error due to:

```
When(specific_time__isnull=False, then=F('specific_time'))
```

because `specific_time` is `TimeField()` in the model and `after_n_values` is an Integer. I actually want to check when a value between (`after_n_values` or `specific_time` exists) then it should return that corresponding value.

But, I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: CASE types integer and time without time zone cannot be matched
LINE 1: ... WHEN "core_songs"."specific_time" IS NOT NULL THEN "core_songs"...
```

Could anyone suggest how can I check here using when clause whether a date is present or empty as shown above?

Comment: Are you sure that `aftervals_songs` in the line `When(after_n_values__isnull=False, then="aftervals_songs")` is correct? Should it maybe be `F('after_n_values')` ?

Comment: yes it works without using F also.